# Compile Solidity to assembly keeping a correspondence with the source code

Tags: solidity, assembly, compilation, compiler

I would like to compile a contract written in Solidity (or even just the part relating to a single method) to study it and understand if I can optimize it.
I already managed to get the bytecode as binary or in its assembly representation using `solc` but I would prefer to keep the original source in the assembly like comments, line per line, similar to what happens with `gcc -S`.

Moreover, I can't understand if the `solc` compiler uses the Yul language as intermediate representation between Solidity and assembly during the compilation, in case it did, how can I view this representation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, the closest you will get is to use `--asm` output from solc.

With solc 0.8 you can get the intermediate Yul representation with `--ir`.

The command

```
solc -o build --asm --ir MetaCoin.sol
```

should generate MetaCoin.evm and MetaCoin.yul files in build directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manually optimize `solc --asm` output you can do it with my EVM assembler :) https://github.com/RafaelSalguero/evm-assembler

It's compatible with `solc --asm` output